# Odoo - Showing google maps snippet inside of Popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, odoo-8

I am working on a module that will allow the user to see the geographical position of a vehicle on Google Maps. i have succeeded so far to show the map on a new tab by passing the coordinates to Maps's JavaScript. Now i need to show that map inside of a popup so the user won't have to leave the odoo tab to get the information.

**google_map.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Localisation de vehicule</title>
        <style>
            html, body { height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0; }
            #map { height: 100%; }
        </style>
        <script>

            function initMap() {
                var querystring = window.location.querystring;

                var mylong = location.search.slice(11,location.search.indexOf("&"));
                var mylati = location.search.slice(location.search.indexOf("latitude=")+9,location.search.indexOf("&key"))

                var myLatLng = {lat: Number(mylong), lng: Number(mylati)};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatLng
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map
              });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map">
        </div>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCf-h2Od2097sfJ14DrgUv3ctmcTe1oHy4&callback=initMap"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**geolocation.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    _name = 'tt.vehicle'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    longitude = fields.Char(string="Longitude", required="True", default="51.6643335")
    latitude = fields.Char(string="Latitude", required="True", default="19.2976092")
    matriculate = fields.Char(string="Matricule", default="58924/A/48")
    # location = fields.Char(string="Coordonnées géographiques", compute="tt_return_location")

    @api.multi
    def tt_locate_vehicle(self):
        return{
                "type": "ir.actions.act_url",
                "url": "http://localhost:63342/odoo/geolocation/google_map.html?longitude=" + self.longitude + "&latitude=" + self.latitude + "&key=AIzaSyAZkVmtvhuKp9U34DlKIicoW3CVEAuM0zM",
                "target": "new",
        }
```

**geolocation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

         <!--Tree view vehicule-->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="vehicle_list_view">
        <field name="name">vehicle.tree</field>
        <field name="model">tt.vehicle</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="matriculate"/>
                <field name="longitude"/>
                <field name="latitude"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
        <!--From view vehicule-->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="vehicle_form_view">
            <field name="name">vehicle.form</field>
            <field name="model">tt.vehicle</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="vehicle_form">
                    <sheet>
                        <group string="Information sur vehicule" colspan="4">
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="matriculate"/>
                            <field name="longitude"/>
                            <field name="
                            <button name="tt_locate_vehicle" string="Localiser" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                            <button name="tt_show_popup" string="popup" type="object" class="oe_
                        </group>
                            <div>
                                <object type="text/html" data="https://www.google.com/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue"><object>
                            </div>

                    </sheet>

                </form>

            </field>
        </record>


        <menuitem id="main_geolocation_menu" name="Géolocalisation"/>
        <menuitem id="geolocation_menu" name="Géolocalisation" parent="main_geolocation_menu"/>
        <menuitem id="geolocation_vehicle_menu" name="Géolocalisation des vehicules" parent="geolocation_menu" action="vehicle_action_view"/>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: @geocodezip, i just got it solved, i was trying to show a little map in odoo form. For that i used <ifram> tag and it worked but i still have a little problem: the url `"http://localhost:63342/odoo/geolocation/google_map.html?longitude=34.681178&amp;latitude=-1.925503&amp;key=AIzaSyAZkVmtvhuKp9U34DlKIicoW3CVEAuM0zM"` contains 2 variables longitude and attitude which i need to get from the model do you have any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: the best way to do that is by parsing xml/html via some python function that will be executed once the user clicks on a  button called **Locate**

Comment: Please edit your question with updates (it is hard to read code in the comments).  If you solved the issue, please post your solution as an answer (and accept it).

Answer (score 0):

I just got it solved, i was trying to show a little map in odoo form. For that i used `<ifram>` tag like so :

```
<div>
                                 <iframe src="http://localhost:63342/odoo/geolocation/google_map.html?longitude=34.681178&amp;latitude=-1.925503&amp;key=AIzaSyAZkVmtvhuKp9U34DlKIicoW3CVEAuM0zM" width="825px" height="500px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                            </div>
```